# Fresco prefetch multiple pictures,How to listen progress?

Tags: fresco

I try user `DataSource<Void> dataSource dataSource.getProgress()`,but `getProgress() return 0.0`,Log print only once.
so,what am I to do?

Answer (score 0):

When you obtain a `DataSource` from the `ImagePipeline`, you need to subscribe to it. All of this is also explained in the Fresco [documentation](http://frescolib.org/docs/datasources-datasubscribers.html).

```
DataSubscriber<T> dataSubscriber =
        new BaseDataSubscriber<T>() {
          @Override
          public void onNewResultImpl(DataSource<T> dataSource) {
            ...
          }
          @Override
          public void onFailureImpl(DataSource<T> dataSource) {
            ...
          }
          @Override
          public void onProgressUpdate(DataSource<T> dataSource) {
            float progress = dataSource.getProgress();
          }
        };
    mDataSource.subscribe(dataSubscriber, mUiThreadImmediateExecutor);
```